# libipopt.so.1: Cannot open shared object file

Tags: bash, dynamic, shared-libraries

Upon performing the basic installation of [Ipopt](http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node14.html), I'm able to compile the example they provided in `Ipopt-3.12.5/Ipopt/examples/hs071_cpp` successfully using the command

```
g++ hs_071_main.cpp hs071_nlp.cpp -I/path/to/build/include/coin -L/path/to/build/lib -lipopt -llapack -lblas -lm -ldl
```

But when I try to run `./a.out`, I get the error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: 
libipopt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've defined `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc`, and I've confirmed that `ls $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` shows `libipopt.so` and `libipopt.so.l`

Comment: you must copy `libipopt.so.1` file to `/lib` or `/usr/lib` then run 'ldconfig' in terminal. after that try to run program again.

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi: If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set correctly this should not be necessary. That's what this environment variable exactly is for.

Comment: What does `ldd ./a.out` tell you?

Comment: Concluding from the fact you link with `libdl`, do you by any means specify the lib to be loaded by `dlopen()` using more then just its **file**name, or do you prefix it by any more or less complete path?

Comment: @MohammadrezaPanahi This did make the error go away, but I'm curious why setting the `LD_LIBARRY_PATH` does not work.

Comment: Perhaps because it's `LD_LIBRARY...` and not `LD_LIBARRY_...`? ;-)

Comment: @alk `ldd ./a.out` shows a list of several libraries, but `libipopt.so.1 => not found`

Comment: Also depeding on the shell you need to `export` the environment variable after setting it. Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/whatever/path/you/want:/any/more/pathes/here:/and/here`

Comment: @alk `export` worked.  So does this mean I can't define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a file such as `.bashrc`?

Comment: Sure you can, just at the appropriate `export` statement to your `.bashrc`

Comment: @alk Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export the environment variable after setting it.

Try

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/whatever/path/you/want:/any/more/pathes/here:/and/here
```

When setting this by default better use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/your/personal/so/lib/path1:/path2
```

This way you do not overwrite any system wide search paths which might already have been set.