# Anaconda install pyipopt: libipopt.so.1

Tags: python-2.7, ld, ipopt

I'm completely new to Python and most aspects of compiling C.

My default python interpreter is the anaconda interpreter for python 2.7. I'm trying to install pyipopt following these instructions: https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt. Pyipopt installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyipopt`, but when I try `import pyipopt` I get an error saying that pyipopt wasn't found.

I then tried copying the installed folder into Anaconda's pkgs folder. At first it said `Error: import pyipopt ImportError: can not find libipopt.so.1`, but then it went back to saying that pyipopt wasn't found after I logged out and back in.

I then tried copying the installed folder into `{anaconda_dir}/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, but it again said `Error: import pyipopt ImportError: can not find libipopt.so.1`. The troubleshooting section on the github page says to copy `libipopt.so.1` into a folder accessible to ld, but I'm not really sure which folder would fit the bill.

Could someone give a brief explanation or link on how python finds C libraries or other .so libraries? Thanks.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/37974827/2029132

Comment: [Thislink](https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt/issues/16) could also help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you've provided guides the user to install using `sudo`. When one does that, the packaged is installed in the system. And since you are using python from Anaconda and not from the system, Anaconda cannot find `pyipopt`, since it is not on its path.

I suggest that you try installing using:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

Note that I removed the `sudo`.

Regarding the `libipopt.so.1` library, maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37975815/2029132) from @alk can help you.